# How can I restructure a JSON array?

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure such that within each child there are fields, and one of these fields is another object. Like this:

```
[ 0: {
      a: "a"
      b: "b"
      c: "c"
      d: "d"
      user: {
          id: "1",
          f: "f"
         }
     },
  1: {
      a: "a"
      b: "b"
      c: "c"
      d: "d"
      user: {
          id: "2",
          f: "f"
         }
     },
  2: {
      a: "a"
      b: "b"
      c: "c"
      d: "d"
      user: {
          id: "1",
          f: "f"
         }
     }
]
```

I would like to somehow reverse it or restructure it, so that all the fields are within the field that contains an object and if id is repeated merge it, I will try to exemplify it:

```
    [ 0: {
      user: [{
          id: "1",
          f: "f",
          a: "a"
          b: "b"
          c: "c"
          d: "d"
         },{
          id: "1",
          f: "f",
          a: "a"
          b: "b"
          c: "c"
          d: "d"
         }]
     },
  1: {
      user: {
          id: "2",
          f: "f",
          a: "a",
          b: "b",
          c: "c",
          d: "d",
         }
     }
]
```

Comment: You'll need to write a function to do so. You're expected to make an effort and show your work on SO. What have you tried?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be [valid json](https://jsonlint.com/). And as Dan O has pointed out, this isn't an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```js
const input =  { 0: { c: 1, d: 2, e: { a: 3, b: 4 } }};

const mapObj = (obj, map) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ([k, map(v)])));

const result = mapObj(input, ({ c, d, e }) => ({ e: { c, d, ...e }}));


console.log(result);
```

You can use object [destructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)#Parallel_assignment) to get the objects, and then compose new ones.

Comment: and an expanded code format. we're not playing code golf, here.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete dynamic approach, you could look for properties as objects and collect the keys, and, if not, collect the properties in an object for later assigning these properties to a single nested object.

If necessary, iterate nested properties, if more than one is found.

```js
function refine(object) {
    var temp = {},
        target = [],
        remove = [];

    Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
            target.push(k);
            return;
        }
        temp[k] = v;
        remove.push(k);
    });
    if (target.length === 1) {
        Object.assign(object[target[0]], temp);
        remove.forEach(k => delete object[k]);
    }
    target.forEach(k => refine(object[k]));
}

var data =  { 0: { c: 1, d: 2, e: { a: 3, b: 4} }, 1: { c: 5, d: 6, e: { a: 7, b: 8 } } };

refine(data);

console.log(data);
```